# Laravel belongsTo relationship depend on parent table column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got a user and an activity table. A user can have many activities and an activity belongs to a user.

**User**

```
id | name | email
```

**Activity**

```
id | subject_type | subject_id | description
```

I'm having trouble making the belongsTo relationship for activity because it depends on 2 columns. The user id is stored in the subject_id activiy table with the subject type = user model. So it will look something like this:

```
id |  subject_type    |  subject_id | description
 1 |  App\Models\User |     2       | some description ...
```

Right now I've come up with:

**Activity model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'subject_id')
        ->where('subject_type', User::class);
}
```

but it's wrong because subject_type is in activity column.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a polymorphic relationship between models.

A polymorphic relationship allows the child model to belong to more than one type of model using a single association. For example, imagine you are building an application that allows users to share blog posts and videos. In such an application, a Comment model might belong to both the Post and Video models.

Update User model:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    // some stuff
 
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Activity::class, 'subject');
    }
}
```

Update Activity model:

```php
class Activity extends Model
{
    // do some stuff

    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function scopeUserType(Builder $builder): Builder
    {
        return $builder->whereSubjectType(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then usage:

```php
        // get the activities of a specific user
        $activities = $user->activities;

        // get the activities of all users
        $activities = Activity::userType()->get();
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations